# Android map overlay issue

Tags: android, overlay, android-maps, itemizedoverlay

I have a set of points(5-10) that needs to be overlayed on the map.  I am able to perform the overlay function correctly, the markers corresponding to the points are displayed on the map. But android skips adding the first two points for some reason. Any clue why that happens?

```
03-21 15:18:58.703: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:Yann Martel 40.443299 -79.948573
03-21 15:18:58.703: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:American Landscapes: Treasures from the Parrish Art Museum  40.305861 -79.544878
03-21 15:18:58.703: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:Paul Thek: Diver, A Retrospective 40.443299 -79.948573
03-21 15:18:58.703: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:In My Father's House 40.443486 -79.995576
03-21 15:18:58.703: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:Ben Franklin: In Search of a Better World 40.446619 -79.992163
03-21 15:18:58.707: INFO/System.out(22021): added today marker:Ordinary Madness 40.443299 -79.948573
```

All these are the points are added to the overlaym after which the `populate()` method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yann Martel, Paul Thek, and Ordinary Madness all have the same exact Coordinates. So all points are there, just on top of each other.

Comment: ... hahahaa..thank you for that! dint even think about that. is there a way to show all of them ?

Comment: Yeah, move the geopoints so they aren't on top of each other.